# Fail to add dynamic slot to Qobject. Pyside support at most 50 dynamic slots

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qwidget

Hi I have developed a small application with Pyside and python 2.6

which has multiple Widgets creation and deletion on screen.

but after some time it shows following error and crash application

**Fail to add dynamic slot to Qobject. Pyside support at most 50 dynamic slots.**

Please somebody explain me how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance !!

I have shared some main part of code 
first part is scroll_box and second is widgets which are added in scroll_box in rows

```
 
author = 'prashant'
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import comres.recursiveLoad_files as recurse
import os
import re
verbose = False
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s
```

class my_dropable_scroll_box(QtGui.QScrollArea):
    def **init**(self,parent=None):
        super(my_dropable_scroll_box,self).**init**(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1800, 600))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollAreaWidgetContents"))
        self.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_main = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_main.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_main"))
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_main.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_main)
        self.pro = None
        self.all_sh = []
        self.data_store_wdg = {}
        self.data_store_qobject = {}
        self.data_store_groupbx = {}

```
def start_reading_data(self, path):
    date_from_recuse= {'Plate': [{'file_name': '/home/prashant/Desktop/Ingest_Tool/downloadPath/Dummy/Plate_test/right/I_022_bf_1030_bg01_v2_right.####.exr', 'end_frame': '1258', 'start_frame': '1001'}], 'Lut': [{'file_name': '/home/prashant/Desktop/Ingest_Tool/downloadPath/Dummy/lutes/CA001_cineon_v01.spi1d', 'end_frame': '', 'start_frame': ''}], 'Reference': [{'file_name': '/home/prashant/Desktop/Ingest_Tool/downloadPath/Dummy/bunch/TFH_CA500_001_pradeepk_comp_v009_1009.png', 'end_frame': '', 'start_frame': ''}], 'Conflict': [{'file_name': '/home/prashant/Desktop/Ingest_Tool/downloadPath/Dummy/CA500/bla_bla_CA500.nfo', 'end_frame': '', 'start_frame': ''}]}
    self.update_my_ui(date_from_recuse)

def update_my_ui(self, ingest_item, firstUi=True):
    self.tobe_ingest_item = ingest_item
    index_no = 0
    all_ingest = self.tobe_ingest_item.keys()
    for inget_typ in all_ingest:
        for obj in self.tobe_ingest_item[inget_typ]:
            if verbose : print inget_typ, obj
            filenm = obj['file_name']
            self.data_store_qobject[filenm] = QtGui.QWidget()
            self.data_store_qobject[filenm].setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            self.data_store_groupbx[filenm] = QtGui.QGroupBox()
            self.data_store_groupbx[filenm].setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            lyot = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            lyot.addWidget(self.data_store_qobject[filenm])
            self.data_store_groupbx[filenm].setLayout(lyot)
            self.data_store_groupbx[filenm].setStyleSheet('Border : 1px solid grey')
            self.data_store_wdg[filenm] = Ui_Form(self.pro)
            self.data_store_wdg[filenm].setupUi(self.data_store_qobject[filenm])

            '''
            check shstre
            '''
            if inget_typ == 'Plate':
                shstreval, filenm2 = recurse.stereoMatchname(filenm)
                self.data_store_wdg[filenm].shstre.setCurrentIndex(shstreval)
                self.data_store_wdg[filenm].file_name.setText(filenm2)

            if verbose: print filenm
            self.data_store_wdg[filenm].in_type.setCurrentIndex(self.data_store_wdg[filenm].in_type.findText(inget_typ))
            self.data_store_wdg[filenm].file_name.setText(obj['file_name'])

            self.data_store_wdg[filenm].fstart.setText(obj['start_frame'])
            self.data_store_wdg[filenm].fend.setText(obj['end_frame'])

            '''
            setversion
            '''
            take_base_nm = os.path.basename(obj['file_name']).split('.')[0]
            split_name = take_base_nm.split('_')
            p = re.compile(r'(^v\d+)')
            version = 0
            for nm in split_name:
                m = p.match(nm)
                if m and nm[1:].isdigit():
                    version = int(nm[1:])
                    if len(nm)-len(str(version)) == 1:
                        self.data_store_wdg[filenm].version.setPrefix('v')
                    elif len(nm)-len(str(version)) == 2:
                        self.data_store_wdg[filenm].version.setPrefix('v0')
                    else:
                        self.data_store_wdg[filenm].version.setPrefix('v00')
            self.data_store_wdg[filenm].version.setValue(version)

            if inget_typ == 'Conflict':
                self.data_store_wdg[filenm].in_type.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red;')
                self.data_store_wdg[filenm].resolve.setChecked(0)
            self.verticalLayout_main.insertWidget(index_no + 1, self.data_store_groupbx[filenm])
            index_no += 1

def clear_my_widget(self):
    for no in range(1,self.verticalLayout_main.count()-1):
        self.verticalLayout_main.itemAt(no).widget().deleteLater()
    self.data_store_wdg.clear()
    self.data_store_qobject.clear()
    self.data_store_groupbx.clear()
    self.data_store_wdg = {}
    self.data_store_qobject = {}
    self.data_store_groupbx = {}
```

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def **init**(self, pro):
        self.pro = pro

def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
    Form.resize(1800, 600)
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(Form)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
    self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
    self.resolve = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
    self.resolve.setMinimumWidth(60)
    self.resolve.setChecked(1)
    self.isforce = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
    self.isforce.setMinimumWidth(60)
    self.isforce.setChecked(0)
    self.isforce.setDisabled(1)
    self.in_type = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
    self.in_type.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("in_type"))
    self.in_type.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.in_type.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.in_type.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.shname = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
    self.shname.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("shname"))
    self.shname.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(Form)
    self.progressBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("progressBar"))
    self.file_name = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.file_name.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("file_name"))
    self.version = QtGui.QSpinBox(Form)
    self.version.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("spinBox"))
    self.shstre = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
    self.shstre.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("sterro"))
    self.fstart = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.fstart.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("fstart"))
    self.fend = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.fend.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("fend"))
    self.destination_path = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.destination_path.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Destination_path"))
    self.source_path = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.source_path.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Source_path"))
    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    self.my_changes()
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
    self.in_type.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "Plate", None))
    self.in_type.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "Reference", None))
    self.in_type.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "Conflict", None))
    self.shname.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "shName", None))
    self.file_name.setText(_translate("Form", "file name", None))
    self.fstart.setText(_translate("Form", "StartFrame", None))
    self.fend.setText(_translate("Form", "End_Frame", None))
    self.source_path.setText(_translate("Form", "Source_path", None))
    self.destination_path.setText(_translate("Form", "Destination_path", None))

def my_changes(self):
    self.filesize = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    self.filesize.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("fstart"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.resolve)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.isforce)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.shname)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.in_type)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.version)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.shstre)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.file_name)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.fstart)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.fend)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.filesize)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.destination_path)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.source_path)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

    self.version.setPrefix('v')
    self.version.setValue(1)
    self.shstre.addItems(['mono','shstre'])

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Upgrade to a more recent version of PySide: see [BUG 312](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-bz-archive/312.html).

Comment: Hi Irshad here is the code